# Angular4 Chart Library

Tags: angular, charts

How Do I Create this type of Graph or with which library in Tech-Stack:
Angular4?

[Group X Axis Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl5X5.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that can do a bar chart. For example this one: . ChartJS https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

you install it by it's npm command:

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

This is an Angular option

Comment: Like the chart given in image?